Understanding the Simplified Perspective in OCB Security Proof: Exploring the Role of Collisions and Oracle Models
In the security proof of OCB (Offset Codebook Mode), it appears that only collisions at the input and output of the block cipher are considered.
Typically, security proofs for cryptographic modes involve the use of an oracle and the concept of two worlds, aiming to demonstrate that the adversary's probability of distinguishing between these worlds is negligible.
How does the OCB security proof achieve its goals given this simplified perspective?
